# Jquery Queue() Each() with Delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array: result[i]. I'd like to loop through each field in the array and append it to an element in my page.

```
$("tr:first").after(result[i]);
```

But I'd like this to happen with a delay.

Been trying to grock how queues work with each loops and a delay, but I just can't seem to work it out. I can get a delay, but only before they're all appended.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2):

```
$.each(result, function(idx, val) {
    $("tr:first").delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).after(val);
        next();
    });
});
```

Just to be complete, this is for jQuery 1.4. In earlier versions, the callback should look like:

```
function() {
    // do whatever here
    $(this).dequeue();
}
```

Comment: It needed $(this). before the after to work, but it only appended the first one.

Comment: @jackreichert: Yep, I fixed it. Should work now (assuming you use jQuery 1.4).

Comment: Sweet. Shouldn't this be `function(next) { after(val); next(); }` ?

Comment: perfect, on to the next challenge =) randomizing the delay. But I'm pretty sure that Math.random will do that for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Victor Nicollet: Uhm are you referring to the actual version? I already fixed the `next` thing. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I actually wrote the comment while you were editing it, and failed to notice it was fixed afterward >_<

Answer (score 2):

Behold, the power of recursion:

```
(function append(i) {
  if (i >= result.length) return;
  $('tr:first').after(result[i]);
  setTimeout(function(){append(i+1)},1000);
})(0);
```

You may add an additional setTimeout depending on whether you need the first item to appear immediately or after a delay.

Comment: It's defining an anonymous (yes, silly name) function called append, and calling it straight away with an argument of `0`. The () around the function are there to make sure it's an anonymous function - otherwise, the parser might mistake it for a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(result).each(function(i) {
    $("tr:first").delay(1000).after(result[i]);
});
```

Comment: This would append *all* results at t=1000, instead of result one at t=1000, result two at t=2000, result three at t=3000 and so on.

Comment: depends how you look at the question

Comment: Actually, **"I can get a delay, but only before they're all appended."** eliminates your interpretation. Look harder. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could handle this is by looping over your result array and setting up a bunch of setInterval or .delay() function calls, with delays that vary based upon the array index.  For example:

```
for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ){
  $('tr:first').delay(i*1000).after(result[i]);
}
```

To be sure, *this isn't as good a solution* as the recursive one provided by @Victor above, but it's another approach in case you don't like recursion for whatever reason.

Comment: Careful there. Using `$.each()` is safer than a for-loop due to the scoping rules for `i`

Comment: Sorry, never used `$.each()` for array spanning before, so I wouldn't feel good trying to write code off the cuff that uses it.  =)